# Hibernate, forçar nome de tabela em caixa baixa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Estou utilizando o Hibernate 5.2.1.Final como implementação para lidar com banco de dados MySQL. O problema é que as tabelas estão sendo geradas com a primeira letra em caixa alta, gostaria de forçar para ser tudo em caixa baixa via arquivo de persistência. Atualmente meu arquivo é esse:

```xml
<persistence-unit name="testeUP" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.56.100:3306/locadora"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1QAZxsw2"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.diaLect" value="org.hibernate.diaLect.MySQLDiaLect"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

É possível forçar este comportamento? Se sim, como?

Comment: Há algum motivo para usar L maiúsculo ao invés de minúsculo nas palavras *diaLect* de "`hibernate.diaLect`" e também em "`org.hibernate.diaLect.MySQLDiaLect`"? Acho que isso deveria ser minúsculo.

Comment: Amigo sugiro que consulte este material, infelizmente estou sem tempo para te ajudar mas sugiro a leitura desse tutorial (está em inglês): [Implementing a Custom Naming Strategy With Hibernate](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/implementing-a-custom-namingstrategy-with-hibernate/ "Implementing a Custom Naming Strategy With Hibernate")

Answer (score 5):

Nas suas entidades, utilize a anotação [`@Table`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Table.html). Eis um exemplo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tabela_caixa_baixa")
public class MinhaTabela implements Serializable {
    // ...
}
```

Quando a anotação `@Table` está ausente, entende-se que o nome da tabela será o padrão (*default*). O padrão é deixar o *persistence provider* (no seu caso, o Hibernate) dar o nome que ele achar melhor.

Como o que você quer é um comportamento diferente do padrão (não deixar o Hibernate dar o nome do jeito que ele quiser), então você especifica o comportamento desejado por meio do uso da anotação.

Comment: Entendi, isso ajuda bastante. Mas existe alguma configuração que ao menos faz com que o hibernate não leve em conta a diferença de caixa alta e baixa quanto ao nome das tabelas?

Comment: @Fábio Como assim? Os bancos de dados em geral não diferenciam maiúsculas de minúsculas para nomes de tabelas e colunas em instruções dos tipos `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` e `DELETE`. Assim sendo se na sua anotação estiver `"tabela_caixa_baixa"`, mas no banco de dados estiver `"Tabela_CAIXA_BaIXa"`, vai funcionar do mesmo jeito a aplicação. A única diferença significativa está que se/quando o hibernate der um `CREATE TABLE`, ele vai enviar o nome da tabela para o banco de dados do jeito que estiver na anotação e assim ele será registrado.

Comment: Atualmente não estou utilizando a marcação para indicar o nome das tabelas, ou seja, o hibernate está pegando o nome da classe. No arquivo de persistência estou utilizando uma instrução para criar a tabela caso não exista no banco, porém, no banco já tenho a tabela com o nome escrito em caixa baixa, mas o hibernate está criando uma variação em caixa alta conforme o padrão transcrito na classe. Queria ignorar a forma como está no banco e considerar independente se é caixa baixa ou alta.